# Passing Data View-to-Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've tried several various was to move data from a view to the controller in order to sort a new view, but I am unable to get the data to pass.  Here is what I have:

**View 1**

```
@model TabCheckout.checkout
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Select the Letter of Your Last Name";
}
<h3>Select the Letter of Your Last Name</h3>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @{int i = 0;
                    foreach (string letter in ViewBag.Letters)
                    {
                        i++;
                        if (i == 9)
                        {
                            i = 0;
                        @Html.Raw("<br />")
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <input type='submit' id='@letter' name='selectletter' value='@letter' formaction='Names' />                    
                            }
                        }
                    }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Letters(string selectletter)
        {
            List<string> letters = new List<string>();
            for (int y = 0; y < 26; y++)
            { 
                char filter = Convert.ToChar(65 + y);
                string letter = filter.ToString();
                letters.Add(letter);
            }
            ViewBag.Letters = letters;
            GlobalVariable.selectletter = Convert.ToString(selectletter);
            return View(GlobalVariable.selectletter);
        }
        public ActionResult Names()
        {
            //     var namesrt = from s in db.users
            //                   select s;
            //     namesrt = namesrt.Where(s => s.LastName.StartsWith(GlobalVariable.letter));
           // ViewBag.UserID = new SelectList(namesrt, "UserID", "FullName", null);
            ViewBag.UserID = new SelectList(db.users, "UserID", "FullName", null);
            return View();
        }
```

**View 2**

```
@model TabCheckout.checkout
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Select Your Name";
}
<h3>Select Your Name - @GlobalVariable.selectletter</h3>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @{int i = 0;
                    foreach (var item in ViewBag.UserID as SelectList)
                    {
                        i++;
                        if (i == 9)
                        {
                            i = 0;
                            @Html.Raw("<br />")
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <input type="submit" name="@item.Text" value="@item.Text" formaction="Vehicles">
                        }
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I feel like the majority of the problem has to do with my Controller verbiage.  I've tried using request name to string, FormCollection, and the current mess.

Thank you for your help and your understanding of my limited skill level.

Here is the model for full disclosure:

**Model**

```
namespace TabCheckout
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

    [Table("NewsData_Tab.checkout")]
    public partial class checkout
    {
        public int CheckoutID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int User { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("User")]
        public virtual user users { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Vehicle { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Vehicle")]
        public virtual vehicle vehicles { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Equipment { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeOut { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeIn { get; set; }
        public checkout()
        {
            TimeOut = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
    public static class GlobalVariable
    {
        public static string selectletter { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public ActionResult Names(FormCollection form)
    {

        var letter = form["selectletter"];

        ViewBag.UserID = new SelectList(db.users, "UserID", "FullName", null);
        return View();
    }
```

It works for me!

Comment: Thank you Guiherme!  I was putting the FormCollection under Letters instead of Names within the Controller.